# Preventing 'members' from changing content approval setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions, content-approval

We use a controlled documents system with flows that's an integral part of our business processes and ISO compliances.

We've struck upon a situation where group members (specifically O365 Group Members) by dint of having Edit as the default permission in SPO can turn off the requirement for content approval for submitted items.

It also appears that this setting isn't audited in either SPO's own audit logs, or in the Compliance/Purview portal either.

Is this a uniquely "us" problem? Or has anyone else ran into the same? And if so, how did you remediate it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you can tighten up the security. There is an out of the box permission level called Contribute which is similar to Edit, but doesn't allow for the management of lists.

You could either:-

- set the permissions for the site's Members group to have the Contribute permission level instead of Edit.
- modify the Edit permission level so that you remove the Manage Lists permission.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Paul, makes perfect sense - just makes for a challenging fix as some users will need to some of the functionality that edit/manage lists provide - so probably means having to tier more groups - and still doesn't present any audit functionality - something that MS has been notoriously lacking in for SharePoint since the dawn of time.